# Find all hashtags

Tags: python, list, oop, twitter

I have a class Tweet that contains several tweets. Then there's a list that contains all the tweets. These tweets also have users, amount of retweets and age, which is not relevant to my question. Only content matters.

- tweet1 = Tweet("@realDonaldTrump", "Despite the negative press covfefe #bigsmart", 1249, 54303)
- tweet2 = Tweet("@elonmusk", "Technically, alcohol is a solution #bigsmart", 366.4, 166500)
- tweet3 = Tweet("@CIA", "We can neither confirm nor deny that this is our first tweet. #heart", 2192, 284200)
- **tweets = [tweet1, tweet2, tweet3]**

I need to get a list of all the hashtags, but I only get the one from the 1st tweet with my code.

```
for x in tweets:
    return re.findall(r'#\w+', x.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning after the first iteration of the loop. You need to go through all tweets and add the hastags to a list:

```
def get_hashtags(tweets):
    result = []
    for x in tweets:
        result.extend(re.findall(r'#\w+', x.content))
    return result
```

For sorting, you can use a defaultdict to add up the reweets. Then, sort by the count.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_hashtags_sorted(tweets):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for x in tweets:
        for hashtag in re.findall(r'#\w+', x.content):
            result[hashtag] += x.retweets
    sorted_hashtags = sorted(tweets.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    return list(sorted_hashtags)
```

Comment: Thank you! I then need to sort these hashtags by popularity, which is the sum of its tweets' retweets. I suppose I need a dictionary with hashtags as keys and popularity as values. Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: updated for that

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it to work. Did this for sorting: sorted(result, key=result.get, reverse=True)